# How to insert already displayed div in print function

Tags: javascript, html, printing

How can I insert div that is already shown on web page in the print function.

This is the function:

```
function printHTML(input){
  var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
    document.body.appendChild(iframe);

  iframe.contentWindow.document.write(input);
  iframe.contentWindow.print();
  document.body.removeChild(iframe); 
}

printHTML('<h1>Test!</h1>');
```

But I need to put inside something that is already shown on the webpage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass clone of your div and appendf in iframe body.
Modified code: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CFypf/1/)

```
function printHTML(clonedDive){
  var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
    document.body.appendChild(iframe);

  iframe.contentWindow.document.body.appendChild(clonedDive);
  iframe.contentWindow.print();

  document.body.removeChild(iframe); 
}

printHTML( document.getElementById("divid").cloneNode(true));​
```

Comment: What is the purpose of cloneNode here?

Comment: Instead of moving div from current window it will create clone of it. if you do not clone the div it will move entire div from current div. you can see the difference in jsfiddle I provided remove clone method.

Comment: thank you for this, is it possible to have a trigger event when you click on the X button on the print form? I'm asking you because I can see that you know some stuff about printing

Comment: Do you mean close button? if so see jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/CFypf/2/. You can use window.onunload event.

Comment: This means you are trying to insert an HTMLDivElement as a text. are you doing something like .innerHTML = Element? show me code

Comment: Sorry I do not know. I think you should ask a new question for this problem.

Comment: Ok, I think that my div with google maps is not shown because function is cloning div from the state when it was initialized and not after the I click function. For example I have a table so when you click the record, google maps div is shown. And when I perform print function I only see table when it was initialized and not when it is clicked

Comment: Is there any function to print entire content? Because I think that only one page is printed and I have more than one page of content

Comment: I dont think so, You should ask these question on stackoverflow? it will help others to learn.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `document.getElementById()` to get whatever you need.

E.g. to get some div on your page:

```
var someDiv = document.getElementById("divId");
printHTML(someDiv);
```